# Extracting tables in line from PDF

Tags: python, python-camelot, tabula-py

I'm trying to extract text from PDF files in bulk. I found that I can use tabula/camelot for extracting tables, but I'm unsure how I can put them in the appropriate places. The closest I've come is using `tabulizer::extract_text()` and `tabulizer::extract_tables()`, and trying to match table text to replace. This seems unwieldy - is there a better solution?

Comment: Not really.  PDFs were simply not designed to be used in these ways.  PDFs were designed to be a "fake printer".  Strings that are close together on the page might be far apart inside the document.  It's always going to be a struggle.

Comment: @TimRoberts I was thinking it may be possible to figure out, based on location of the tables, do the replacing. Does this not work in practice? I'm unsure how this would be implemented

Comment: `extract_text` gives you not only the text but the location, but it's still up to you do figure out how the blocks of text relate.  It will tell you "the word 'gives' is at x=230 y=700" and "the word 'you' is at x=285 y=700".  There's still a lot of work to do.